# Switching between Google Maps Android API v2 DEBUG and RELEASE API Key

Tags: java, android, google-maps

Just finished coding an Android app and am preparing to release it to the Play Store. During development, I obtained a Google Maps API Key using my debug.keystore, and placed this key in my Manifest, like so:

```
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="MY_API_KEY" />
```

However, I've now signed my app with my release certificate, and thus got a new API key from Google Maps. For testing purposes, is there a way to keep both the old (debug) and new (release) API key in my Manifest, with a switch that loads the proper one at run time? Ex:

```
if (debug) {
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="DEBUG_API_KEY" />
}

else if (release) {
<meta-data
  android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
  android:value="RELEASE_API_KEY" />
}
```

Cheers!

Comment: Only thing I've been able to do is comment out either as needed.  Takes ten seconds.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You may use the same key for multiple signing keys or even multiple applications.

On the API Console edit allowed apps and add SHA;package pairs, one pair per line.

Answer (score 0):

```
      <!-- RELEASE key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/release_map_key" />

        <!-- DEBUG key -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
            android:value="@string/debug_map_key" />
```

> You add multiple api key in manifest like above. But you can use same api key for both debug and release.