# Google Maps Key between development and release

Tags: android, google-play, key, release, google-maps-api-2

I have google maps key in my app, it works fine no problem

the problem is when i release my app on google play, I cant see google maps!

I read in some posts that I do not have to change the key as I can use the same for both release and development [Google Maps Android V2 debug and release key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19251155/google-maps-android-v2-debug-and-release-key) and [Switching between Google Maps Android API v2 DEBUG and RELEASE API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17886937/switching-between-google-maps-android-api-v2-debug-and-release-api-key)

and some other posts that say I have to get another key for release [Generating Google map Release API Key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10386770/generating-google-map-release-api-key)

Now in my case same key does not work.

I used the link in the google_maps_api.xml to generate the key (application id is the same in release and in development and release) which is

https://console.developers.google.com/flows/enableapi?apiid=maps_android_backend&keyType=CLIENT_SIDE_ANDROID&r=A9:DC:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??%3Bcom.?????.???????.???

is this part A9:DC:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:??:?? differ between development and release?

what do i have to do.

thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to create two keys. One for development and one for production.

> What is the difference between development and production key?

When you compile application for development it's signed with a development key and when you prepare your application for production you sign it with a production key.

Google Maps API key is based on this key. So you have to create two keys one for the time when you compile application for development and one for production.

> Can I have the same Google Maps API Key for Development and
>   Production?

Google Maps API requires you provide SHA1 and package name. Package name stays same for development and production. 
You create SHA1 from a key. This key is different for development and production. So you have to create two different SHA1 and use them for creating key in Google API Console.

You can read more on how to create development and release SHA1 for creating API KEY on Android official page https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/start#display_your_apps_certificate_information

Comment: To create the key I used the same SHA1 and application id, which are the same and will generate a key that works for both, isnt it?

Comment: I updated the answer. You need to create two different SHA1 and then use that for creating API Key.

Comment: How to create a new SHA1? the link you provided does not work... I thought SHA1 is fixed for the app and can not be changed!

Comment: @Ken Why the link doesn't work? It has the complete information with commands.

Comment: I get this 500. Internal server error.

An error occurred while trying to fulfill your request. That's all we know.